# Upload any format of files with ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a file input that I Want Save in Database,
My Ajax Code is Here:

```
   $(document).ready(function (event) {
                $('#ProSave').click(function (event) {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf- 
                             token"]').attr('content')
                        }});
     var file  = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', file);
     formData.append('_token', $('input[name=_token]').val());
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/Product/Digital/Save',
                        method: 'post',
                        data: formData,
                        contentType : false,
                        processData : false,
                        success: function(response){
                            // window.location.reload();
                        }});
                });

            });
```

And in Contoller I Want to change name of file and move to files path with this code:

```
if ($request->file('file')) {
      $file = $request->file('file');
        $randonName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $file- 
        >getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('/files'), $randonName);
    $product->product_file  = $randonName;
 }
```

When I Want Upload pdf file or image with 3 mb size I give this Error:
`413 Payload Too Large`
How I Can upload any format with 250mb limit size?

Comment: What are the upload limit of your PHP and whatever your web server is?

Comment: limit of file is 1Mb and I use localhost